# what css framework suits better for embedded js applications?

Tags: javascript, javascript-remoting, css, stylesheets

I have some embedded js application consuming remote scripts from Force.com, right now I'm using `bootstrap` but it has a lot of conflict with the `Force.com` default css. I want to know if there is a css framework that suits better for my needs.

Thank you.

Comment: bootstrap is the best. so you are facing conflict with the Force.com default css. Use namespace bootstrap so. It will work awsome  http://scottvonschilling.com/blog/2014/08/using-bootstrap-in-visualforce/

Comment: That would be easy to implement in the apps I actually have, thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you're building apps to run in Salesforce, I'd use the Salesforce Lightning Design System which is all CSS, open source, and matches the new styling of Lightning Experience.

https://www.lightningdesignsystem.com/